# Counting States for $N$ SUSY in Wess and Bagger

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, supersymmetry, degrees-of-freedom

In Wess and Bagger's book, we calculate how many states are there for massive cases under $N$ SUSY.

We couldn't follow the table on page 14. What is "Spin" here (absolute value?), and how can we get the numbers?

We thought that they might be binomial coefficients, but they're not.

Comment: The authors go out of their way to detail how the table is gotten by ladder recursions in p 13. Yes, spin indicates positive spins, and you are meant to add the CPT conjugates, unless the multiplet goes all the way to the negative spin states, being self-conjugate.  In every case, reassure yourself the bosons d.o.f. match the sermonic ones.  Yes binomial coefficients and Pascal's triangles and their sums, with some wrinkles. Show your work.

Comment: p 36 of Peter West's *Introduction to Supersymmetry and Supergravity* counting helicity states might be more to your liking. It is wonderfully friendlier.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that!